# How to use sequential statements (e.g. process) to make constant value but without wait?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

For the sake of consistency and ease of maintenance, I would like to make some constants using sequential statements, e.g. in process.

I have defined a range using:

```
subtype FIELD is natural range 3 downto 0;
```

A process that makes the value could then look like:

```
process is
begin
    reg <= (others => '0');
    reg(FIELD) <= (others => '1');
    wait;  -- Error in Xilinx ISE
end process;
```

However, the `wait` is not accepted by Xilinx ISE synthesis tool.

One way is of course to use a non-used signal in a process list, like a clock, but that is a kind of ugly.

The concurrent style would be like:

```
reg <= (FIELD => (others => '1'), others => '0');
```

But FIELD can't be used like that in VHDL.

Is there a way to make constants using sequential statements, but where the `wait` is not required in a `process`?

Comment: you don't need a process to assign constant value to a signal. Do it directly in the Architecture.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that that, but I prefer to use same structure for generating the register contents even if it contains a constant value, so I can later update to non-constant output in the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function to do this.  Note, I don't do any error checking on the range, but isn't difficult to do.

```
-- subtypes
subtype FIELD is natural range 3 downto 0;

-- functions
function test_func(a: std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
    variable result : std_logic_vector(a'left downto a'right) := a;
begin
    result(FIELD) := (others => '1');
    return result;
end function;

-- constants
constant ALL_ZEROS  : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

-- signals
signal reg          : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := test_func(ALL_ZEROS);
```

Comment: Good point using a function to allow sequential statements, and then just use the function to initialize the `reg`.  Maybe `reg` should even be a constant in this case.  Btw. the `ALL_ZEROS` is not needed if result is initialized using `result := (others => '0');` in the start.  I will give it a couple of days to see if this is the best idea.